# p2.js physics engine behavior on Heightfield

Tags: javascript, physics-engine

I am writing a small game consisting of a 'ragdoll' character riding a skateboard.

I have created a 'skateboard park' with some ramps and a jump.

I am using a 'heightfield' object as the ground.  What I notice is that the behavior of the wheels rolling up and down slopes on one side are entirely different that slopes on the other side.. even though the slopes are symmetrical.

Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Here is a codepen to illustrate the problem. http://codepen.io/smatthews1999/pen/uGmaE

and here is an image to explain clearly what the issue is.

[image]